# No Border Around Table in HTML

Tags: css, html, lotus-notes

I am trying this for a while..but no border is appearing for this segment.Please need your help.

```
Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable{border-width: 1px; border-color: #666666; border-collapse: collapse;}|)
Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable th{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 2px; padding: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666; background-color: #09092a;}|)
Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable td{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; border-width: 2px; padding: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666; background-color: #ffffff;}|)
Call stream.writetext(|</style>|)
```

Comment: This is very hard to read, could you format the code so it's readable? It will help generate an answer for you.

Comment: Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable{border-width: 1px; border-color: #666666; border-collapse: collapse;}|) Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable th{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 2px; padding: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666; background-color: #09092a;}|) Call stream.writetext(|table.gridtable td{font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; border-width: 2px; padding: 4px; border-style: solid; border-color: #666666; background-color: #ffffff;}|) Call stream.writetext(||)

Comment: Thanks it, much better..... lol

Comment: Can you put the produced HTML and CSS to a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML renderer in Lotus Notes (at least in older versions) is infamous for not producing results equivalent to standard browsers.

The best thing to do is to try test the same HTML in Chrome or Firefox and make sure it looks the way you expect.

Assuming it does, you may not be able to create a border using CSS. Try using Border="1" as an attribute to your table and see if that renders correctly in Notes.